# How to add a dynamically link in a dynamically added table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I'm a newbie and struggle to add a link, showed like an img in a dynamically added table.

```
 string search = Search.Text;
 IMyData members = new MyData();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 dt = members.Search(search);

 Table t = new Table();
 t.ID = "tblTable";
 TableRow row = null;


 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    row = new TableRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
       TableCell cell = new TableCell();
       if (j == dt.Columns.Count - 1)     //This last field may hava a number
       {
          if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()) > 0)
          {
             link.ID = "link" + i + "_" + j;
             link.NavigateUrl = "members.aspx?showLease=" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
             link.ImageUrl = "img/document.png";
             Page.Controls.Add(link);      // How to put this in a cell, not on page 
          }
          else
          { 
             cell.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
          }
        }
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
      }
      t.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    pnlTable.Controls.Add(t);
```

How can I put the Hyperlink to the cell, and not to the Page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add control in TableCell the way you are doing in Page. Change your code like this

```
Page.Controls.Add(link);//Will add control in page
cell.Controls.Add(link);//Will add control in table cell
```

Comment: Tnx a lot! And with: row.Cells.Add(cell); after, it all was a success :-)

Answer (score 0):

See below, I changed Page.Controls.Add(link) to cell.Controls.Add(link) and moved your Hyperlink declaration into the cell loop. Otherwise if will only be added in the last cell.
But if I see your code it seems that only the last cell will have link or text because of the j == dt.Columns.Count - 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    row = new TableRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
       HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
       TableCell cell = new TableCell();
       if (j == dt.Columns.Count - 1)     //This last field may hava a number
       {
          if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()) > 0)
          {
             link.ID = "link" + i + "_" + j;
             link.NavigateUrl = "members.aspx?showLease=" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
             link.ImageUrl = "img/document.png";
             cell.Controls.Add(link);      // How to put this in a cell, not on page 
          }
          else
          { 
             cell.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
          }
       }
       row.Cells.Add(cell);
     }
     t.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: tnx. It is right that only the last field is having this hyperlink.